# How to hide the Sidebar Nav Menu when a User clicks outside of it using Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My SPA has an Admin Dashboard with a Sidebar Navigation Menu that is visible by default when the viewport is larger than 991px. When the viewport is less than 991px, the Navbar disappears and you have a hamburger icon that you can click to Toggle(show/hide) the Sidebar Menu. Right now the menu will only hide if you click on the little hamburger menu icon a second time. What I want is to close/hide the menu if a User clicks anywhere outside of it. I'm using Bootstrap-Vue for my UI.

So I have a `<b-navbar toggleable="md" type="dark" variant="info"></b-navbar>`.

What I'd like to do is something like this, but I know I'm mixing Javascript and Vue js and not sure exactly how to set this up.

```
data() {
    return {
        sidebarMenu: true
    }
}
```

```
<section class="app-sidebar" v-if="sidebarMenu">
```

```
<div class="main-panel" @click="hideSidebarNavMenu">
```

```
methods: {
    hideSidebarNavMenu() {
        this.sidebarMenu = false;
    },

    const navbarTogglerButton = document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler");

    navbarTogglerButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        this.sidebarMenu = true;
    })
}
```

This main-panel div will contain all of the data for every page, so no matter where they click this `hideSidebarNavMenu` function should get fired.

I need this code to work only when the viewport is less than 991px.
Again, I'm getting some syntax errors in my methods, I believe because I'm trying to write Javascript in my methods attribute.

This is the idea.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized now that in the Free Admin theme that I'm using, when a user clicks on the Hamburger button to toggle the Sidebar, all it does is just add and remove a class called active on the nav element.
Element:

```
<nav id="sidebar" class="sidebar sidebar-offcanvas active">
```

And so this is how I solved it:

```
mounted() {
    var mainPanelDiv = document.querySelector(".main-panel");
    var navbar = document.querySelector("#sidebar");
    mainPanelDiv.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        navbar.classList.remove('active');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `methods` must contains… methods and not code like `const navbarTogglerButton …` This is probably the error you have

attach your event to `.navbar-toggler`

```html
<div class="navbar-toggler" @click="showSidebarNavMenu">
```

```js
methods: {
    hideSidebarNavMenu() {
        this.sidebarMenu = false;
    },

    showSidebarNavMenu() {
        this.sidebarMenu = true;
    },

}
```

Comment: The problem is that div doesn't exist in my HTML, because as mentioned above it's just Bootstrap-Vue's <b-navbar> component that automatically generates the code inside of it. So I'm not sure how to access the div inside dynamically.

Comment: I see, then you need to add your code ```const navbarTogglerButton = document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler");

    navbarTogglerButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        this.sidebarMenu = true;
    })``` once your component or view is mounted. Have a look to the [lifecyle diagram](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) for more details

Comment: Okay and is there a way to only call this function when the viewport or window is less than 991px?

Comment: Also, the sidebar disappears when I click outside of it, but when I click on the navbar-toggler icon I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
and I think it might be because my code/function is in Admin.vue but the <b-navbar> is inside my AppHeader.vue component. How can I fix this?